# npm "decompress" package Arbitrary File Write Error when including @truffle/contract package

Tags: npm, ethereum, package.json, truffle

I'm currently trying to get a Project to run. When I try to install the packages with `npm install` i get `found 12 vulnerabilities (8 low, 4 high) in 68482 scanned packages`. It seems to be a problem with the package `decompress` used in `@truffle/contract`, because this is the audit report:

```
  High            Arbitrary File Write

  Package         decompress

  Patched in      No patch available

  Dependency of   @truffle/contract [dev]

  Path            @truffle/contract > @truffle/interface-adapter > web3 >
                  web3-bzz > swarm-js > decompress

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1217


  High            Arbitrary File Write

  Package         decompress

  Patched in      No patch available

  Dependency of   @truffle/contract [dev]

  Path            @truffle/contract > ethereum-ens > web3 > web3-bzz >
                  swarm-js > decompress

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1217


  High            Arbitrary File Write

  Package         decompress

  Patched in      No patch available

  Dependency of   @truffle/contract [dev]

  Path            @truffle/contract > web3 > web3-bzz > swarm-js > decompress

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1217


  High            Arbitrary File Write

  Package         decompress

  Patched in      No patch available

  Dependency of   decompress [dev]

  Path            decompress

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1217
```

*I copied only the report part with the high vulnerabilities.*

Unfortunately the help link ("https://npmjs.com/advisories/1217") has also no solution.

I get the problem with the `decompress` package when I include the `@truffle/contract` package. These are my dependencies:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/qr-scanner": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "angular": "1.7.9",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": "^2.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.4.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "0.14.0",
    "picomatch": "2.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/cli": "6.3.0",
    "@truffle/contract": "^4.1.13",
    "@types/node": "^10.11.5",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cross-env": "7.0.2",
    "decompress": "^4.2.0",
    "ganache-cli": "6.9.1",
    "http-server": "0.12.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "superagent": "5.2.2",
    "truffle": "5.1.17",
    "truffle-wallet-provider": "^0.0.5",
    "typescript": "3.7.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "*"
  },
```

Can somebody help me with this error.

**Elias**